# numpy.load gets stuck, how to debug?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a function that generates data as a numpy array, but first checks if the data was previously generated and just loads it.

```
if os.path.exists(SUBJECT_DATA_PATH):
    print('Found prepared patches. Loading..')
    vol = np.load(SUBJECT_DATA_PATH)
    return vol
```

This is fast when dealing with ~10 arrays it must load, but for some reason, when I increase the number around 50, the loading gets increasingly slow, up to a point where it seems to freeze...

The size of the arrays is very manageable and I can generate the 50 arrays without any problem. If I don't load the data, and generate it on the fly instead, it is done in seconds. There seem to be something about np.load() that gets VERY slow quickly...

Any obvious hints?

Comment: I would be helpful if you would provide an reproducible example.

Comment: I don't see any problems with the code segment, but you don't show how you accumulate the results.  Does the load make any difference whether you accumulate the results as opposed to just throwing them away.  In other words, you don't give us enough information to help you.

Comment: @hpaulj the fact that you don't see any problems tells me that this is not expected behavior for numpy.load() and helped me to look for other issues, discovering there was an issue with the  drive from where data was being loaded (thank you!)